# MMAL failing to create camera component

Tags: pi-2, camera, raspicam, mmal

I've been messing around with Raspicam and MMAL on my Pi 2 for a bit now and today when I tried to run my code, I got this error. Thought it might be my code, so I tried running one of the example raspicam_test files and I still get this error.

I have tried rebooting, switching Pis, changing power sources, switching SD cards, disabling and re-enabling the camera, updating the firmware and basically anything you can update. I don't have another camera to test it with, but I really hope something else can fix it before I have to get another camera. It was just working yesterday... Thanks!

```
Connecting to camera
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
Failed to create camera componentopen Failed to create camera component/home/pi/raspicam/src/private/private_impl.cpp 103
Error opening camera
```